# Unable to logout using client application

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, single-sign-on, spring-social

I am following this tutorial on https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/ and i've set up custom auth-server and 2 clients. Now I am unable to logout using client, what I am trying is to logout using client X and want my client Z to be logged out of facebook or Github also. 
Any help in this regard will be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok i found out that what i needed was to call `window.location ="http://localhost:8008/logout";`(Authorozation server's URL) from my client's frontend and create a custom logoutSuccessHandler in my central Authorization Server to get back to client referer URL after success logout

```
@Override
public void onLogoutSuccess(HttpServletRequest request,
        HttpServletResponse response, Authentication authentication)
        throws IOException, ServletException {
    if(authentication != null) {
        System.out.println(authentication.getName());
    }
    //perform other required operation

    String URL = request.getContextPath();
    response.setStatus(HttpStatus.OK.value());
    response.sendRedirect(request.getHeader("referer"));
}
```